# What's the meaning of "structure and internal differentiation" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ALL CAPS IS HARD TO PARSE IN GENERAL. IT IS EASIER TO SCAN TEXT WHICH HAS **STRUCTURE AND INTERNAL DIFFERENTIATION**. IN ADDITION, ON THE INTERNET, ALL CAPS IS THE EQUIVALENT OF SHOUTING, AND THEREFORE IS CONSIDERED RUDE, AS SHOUTING IS CONSIDERED RUDE IN PUBLIC.

I know

> structure : the quality of something that is carefully planned, organized, and controlled 
>   internel : existing or located on the inside of something
>   differentiation : the action or process of differentiating.

In the article, he is talking about bad things of writing something in all caps. I don't understand why he said **STRUCTURE AND INTERNAL DIFFERENTIATION**. What's the relation between using capitals and the sentence(IT IS EASIER~).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a text in all caps, it has no structure and it has no internal differentiation.

When you write a text using capital letters only where they are necessary, such text has structure and internal differentiation, and is therefore **easier to scan**.

> What's the relation between using capitals and the sentence(IT IS EASIER~).

The relation is "contrast": the author says

> "All caps: hard to read" **versus** "Regular text: easier to read"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid that I still have two questions. 1. Even though a text is written in all caps, the text has structure as long as it's well-organised. Isn't it? 2. What does it mean that a text has internal differentiation? I'm struggling to understand what internal differentiation means.

Comment: @TingChoe - the author is probably not being strict with his terminology. He wants to stress the importance of not using all caps. He probably meant to say that a regular-sized text has "more clearly identifiable structure". "Internal differentiation" means that **inside** the body of text (internally) there are some differentiating signals (like letter size). If your text is all caps, you have to rely on context to differentiate **Mark** (male name) from **mark** (a common noun), because there's no differentiation in letter size.